# I get the first part 7! / 4!2! is all the arrangement of consonant but What is the logic for P = 7! / 4!? What does this part trying to achieve?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

So, the first part is for getting the number of arrangements for the consonants on MISSISSIPI but the second part it only says vowels can occur together. Which does not make any sense why n = 7? Is that from consonants? And what is the reason for diving it with 4!?

Here is the image for the problem:[image]

Comment: On this site people usually discourage posting links. Please type out the whole problem and specify clearly what you are asking about

Comment: *Mississippi* has two *p*s

Answer (score 2):

The phrasing of the example is very poor.  I also can not quite tell what they want to ask.  If they wanted to ask "How many arrangements of the letters in MISSISSIPPI are there such that all I's occur adjacent to one another?" the answer would be to treat the collection of I's as one large object.  There would be $\dfrac{8!}{4!2!1!1!}$ such arrangements.

If they want to ask "How many arrangements of the letters in MISSISSIPPI have no I's next to one another", first arrange the not-I's in $\dfrac{7!}{4!2!1!}$ number of ways (4 S's, 2 P's, 1 M) and then select spaces between each and/or at either end *simultaneously* to place the I's in in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways to get an answer of $\dfrac{7!}{4!2!1!}\times \binom{8}{4}$ with no I's next to one another.

If they want to ask "How many arrangements of the letters in MISSISSIPPI have at least one I next to another I" then take the answer to the simple case where we don't care and subtract the answer from the previous case, giving $\dfrac{11!}{4!4!2!1!} - \dfrac{7!}{4!2!1!}\times\binom{8}{4}$

I can not think of an interpretation of the question as stated which gives the answer they write and am inclined to think the answer is wrong.  Their number of $210$ they arrive at does not seem to represent anything in the problem and it is illogical to multiply by.